# Avoiding Circular referencing providing too much data

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-ctp5

I followed all the procedures to avoid circular referencing in my Wines/Vineyard project. But I am getting data I do not want:

[image]

**I do not want every listing of wine which has an affiliated vineyard to then have that vineyard list EVERY wine every time the vineyard is listed per wine. How can I stop this? I do not want to do anonymous types.**

**UPDATE:**

My DbContext:

```
    public DataContext()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

My Route Config:

```
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My Controller:

var response = context.Wines.Include("Vineyard").ToList();

Comment: Jakub, what does that have to do with the price of tea in China?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you serializing your data?

Just don't serialize your `wines` collection property. Depending on your serialization mechanism you can either mark it with an attribute (ie. `ScriptIgnore`) or define concrete types (since you don't like anonymous types) and use AutoMapper to copy data.

Binding your EF entities directly to the response of the API is not the best design choice. Every time you modify your db schema your API will change. You could define separate classes that your API controllers will return and use AutoMapper to copy data. That way you decouple your DB schema from your API.

```
namespace API {
    class Wine {
        // properties that you want to return goes here
    }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Wine, API.Wine>(); // Only once during app start
Mapper.Map<Wine, API.Wine>(wine); // AutoMapper will copy data using conventions
```

Comment: Can you offer an example please? Believe me, I would be more than happy to mark your answer as the solution. Lord knows the whole process of using ASP.Net API with Backbone.js is so scarce in the documentation dept to begin with.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a concern with the DbContext as the source for the return. I intend on decoupling later and use Unit of Work, with Ninject. But, assuming I understand you correctly, I do not see how decoupling the datacontext will avoid the unnecessary redundancy in the Json return.

Comment: @ScottMalachowski - your `API.Vineyard` class won't have the `wines` property, so it won't be rendered in json.

Comment: OK I will check it out and report back later. If I can get this to work, I will be more than happy to magnanimously mark your response as the solution.